# Pentaho (kettle) download files from ChEBI FTP server

Tags: ftp, pentaho, kettle

I have a FTP server [link](https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chebi/Flat_file_tab_delimited/) (ChEBI) to the files I need to download. I don't have any additional information (e. g. username, password). How can I download these files using jobs in Pentaho? "Get a file with FTP" gives me an error everytime I try to test the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I figured it out, according to this [post](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/63926-Problem-with-FTP-in-Spoon/) on pentaho forum you need to just enter 'anonymous' in username and your email in password field. Tested it, works fine.